# AcitveMQ C++ connection start() hangs for SSL

Tags: c++, ssl, activemq-cpp

I am trying to get SSL working with the activemq-cpp library. I've had no problems with a normal TCP connection, but with an SSL broker URL the connection `start` method never returns. Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <activemq/library/ActiveMQCPP.h>
#include <activemq/core/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.h>
#include <activemq/util/Config.h>
#include <decaf/lang/System.h>
#include <cms/Connection.h>

/*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 * Build exe with: g++ -std=c++11 -o main -I/usr/include/activemq-cpp-3.9.3 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -lactivemq-cpp -ldl -luuid main.cpp                                                                                                            
 */

int main()
{

  using namespace cms;

  activemq::library::ActiveMQCPP::initializeLibrary();

  {
    // Setting SSL params                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    decaf::lang::System::setProperty( "decaf.net.ssl.keyStore", "/home/pcarter/tmp/active_mq_question/client.pem" );
    decaf::lang::System::setProperty( "decaf.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password" );
    decaf::lang::System::setProperty( "decaf.net.ssl.trustStore", "/home/pcarter/tmp/active_mq_question/broker.pem" );

    // Program works fine with tcp url below                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    //std::string broker_url = "failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)";                                                                                                                                                                              

    // Program locks up in start() call with ssl url below:                                                                                                                                                                                     
    std::string broker_url = "failover:(ssl://localhost:61617)";

    // Create a ConnectionFactory                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    std::unique_ptr<ConnectionFactory> connection_factory(
             ConnectionFactory::createCMSConnectionFactory(broker_url));

    // Create a Connection                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    std::unique_ptr<cms::Connection> connection(connection_factory->createConnection());

    std::cout << "Calling start()" << std::endl;
    connection->start();   // This never returns
    std::cout << "start() returned" << std::endl;

  }
  activemq::library::ActiveMQCPP::shutdownLibrary();

  return 0;
}
```

I am using the default activemq.xml file with the following connectors section

```xml
<transportConnectors>
   <transportConnector name="stomp+ssl" uri="stomp+nio+ssl://0.0.0.0:61613?transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2&amp;needClientAuth=true" />
   <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&amp;needClientAuth=true" />
   <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

However, I don't think the problem is on the broker side. `tcpdump` shows no packets being sent to port 61617 when I run my code.

I have been able to get SSL working with a python STOMP client.

I'm using CentOS 7 and installed ActiveMQ-cpp version 3.9.3 using yum. I'm using the stock gcc compiler version 4.8.5.

My main reference for SSL and C++ was this question: [activemq-cpp c++ client how to use ssl url to connect server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56056174/activemq-cpp-c-client-how-to-use-ssl-url-to-connect-server)

And I created the certs using the procedure described here: [ActiveMQ - STOMP+SSL with Python STOMP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770328/activemq-stompssl-with-python-stomp-client/50774783#50774783)

Answer (score 0):

When I tried removing the "failover" from the broker URI, the program reported an error (this is from a slightly modified test program that catches the `cms:::CMSException`):

```
$ ./main                                                                                                                                                                                               
Caught: Error occurred while accessing an OpenSSL library method:
error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
Error occurred while accessing an OpenSSL library method:
error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
```

Using `gdb` to break on the exception throw, showed that the error was being throw from this snippet:

```cpp
// Here we load the configured KeyStore, this is where the client and server certificate are
// stored, a client doesn't necessary need this if the server doesn't enforce client authentication.
std::string keyStorePath = System::getProperty( "decaf.net.ssl.keyStore" );
this->data->password = System::getProperty( "decaf.net.ssl.keyStorePassword" );

// We assume the Public and Private keys are in the same file.
if( !keyStorePath.empty() ) {
  if( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file( this->data->openSSLContext, keyStorePath.c_str() ) != 1 ) {
     throw OpenSSLSocketException( __FILE__, __LINE__ );
  }
  if( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file( this->data->openSSLContext, keyStorePath.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM ) != 1 ) {
    // This is where exception was thrown
    throw OpenSSLSocketException( __FILE__, __LINE__ );
  }
}
```

The comment about assuming the public and private keys were in the same file explained the cause of the failure. Adding the contents of my `client.key` file (with the private key) to the `client.pem` file fixed the issue.

I was also able to re-add the "failover" to the broker URI after this as well.